# duplicate DNS record side effect

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, dns-zone

I am trying to understand duplicate DNS record in Windows, in the past we had an issue under Linux environment that cause the whole zone to go down (cant access most of the zone due too many incorrect name resolution). In Windows I understand there is DNS scavenger to avoid this but I wondering what is the side effect of having too many duplicate DNS record in Windows environment other that having a problem with calling the servers that has the same entry. is there a chance we might have an issue with the zone itself. and what is the other main issue we might face

Comment: You should start by showing exactly which DNS queries you do and their results, in order to be able to better diagnose the problem, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is yes. since having a duplicate record will make machines with those records are hard to access, since DNS used round robin feature will lead to wrong resolution for the same name each time it is queried.

Example: if I have a record named "X" woth IP "192.168.1.1" and then a newer record with the same name "X" but with different IP "192.168.1.20", while the round robin is enabled DNS server will respond to the queries for this duplicate records differently each time.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate DNS records won't cause the zone to go down. The only issue you'll face with duplicate DNS records is incorrect name resolution for those records.

Comment: Thanks, isnt too many incorrect name resolution will make the zone nearly inaccessible?

Comment: No.............